# How to organize IntelliJ imports correctly after a refactoring

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, import

I was working on a JavaFX Desktop Application and for building reasons, I needed to refactor my project to encapsulate the packages into modules. After that, I realized that my imports were not pointing correctly to the beginning path of the packages.

Exemplifying, one of the imports was like this:
`sudoku.constants.GameState`

And it should've been like:
`com.wissassblog.sudoku.computationlogic.GameState`

Note that it adds the `com.wissassblog` first.

I could set it up manually, but this wouldn't be efficient when working on a larger project. Is there a faster way to correctly point to the right import path?

I've tried the following IntelliJ's tools:

- Adding unambiguous imports on the fly;
- Optimize imports;

But none of this fixed the path automatically.

Comment: If you refactor by relocating or renaming items within the IDE rather than using the file system, I think Idea usually fixes all of the package naming and imports for you.  Otherwise, some manual effort is required.  Usually, the unresolved imports will show in red, I delete them, then their class usage sites in the file are in red as well, I go to each individually and use Alt+Enter | Import Class and Idea will add the correct import, or provide a list of imports to select from if there are multiple packages with the same class name. A power-user may have a more efficient approach.

Comment: Thanks for your tip! After deleting the wrong path it automatically imported the right ones. But it was also necessary to set up the 'Add unambiguous imports on the fly' as default located at 'File > Settings > Editor > General > Auto Import'.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about that feature.  You are a power-user :-).  If you get another vote, you can [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: If you want to fix imports with many files, you could also search for `import sudoku.` and replace all occurencies with `import com.wissassblog.sudoku.`.

Comment: You should use IntelliJ to move things around as it keeps imports working when you do that :) but too late now... anyway, one thing I do when I find myself with bad imports  is just delete  all imports, then go through every place where it's "red' and higt Alt+Enter to get suggestions of fixes, which will show which classes you could import for each case.

Comment: @Renato your comment was identical to mine...